# Code sample HID client using Bluez

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, hid

I'm desperately looking for some C sample source code that describes how to implement a HID client using Bluez. More specifically, I would like to know how to write an application that sends keyboard inputs over bluetooth to another Linux system. (Really, the fact that the receiver is running Linux/Bluez shouldn't matter.)

-Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shamelessly copying from a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177186/is-it-possible-to-make-a-computer-behave-as-a-bluetooth-hid-device/4180098#4180098) of mine:

> Some time ago I found this project:
>
> http://nohands.sourceforge.net/index.html
>
> They emulate a full-blown headset with
>   audio and keyboard controls on the
>   Linux bluetooth stack. If they can
>   emulate something like that, you would
>   probably be able to emulate something
>   simpler like a keyboard.

Comment: That did indeed contain enough info for my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

hidclient http://anselm.hoffmeister.be/computer/hidclient/index.html.en ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is full example apply to keyboard and mouse include get report set report virtual unplug function. the client hid is slave side...
http://fatalfeel.blogspot.tw/2013/09/hid-client-of-bluez.html

and you can refer to  bluez/android/hidhost.c(Master side) see how to connect to slave

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).