# Keyboard emulator

Tags: c++, windows, drivers

I need to create a keyboard emulator for an external device. For example. I connect another computer to my computer with USB and another computer sees my computer as a keyboard. As I understand it, I need to write a driver that will show my computer as external keyboard. Where to begin. And that I can read about this?

Comment: So you have two computers connected together with an USB wire?

Comment: Yes I want to connect two computers through the USB and one computer sees another computer as a keyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send keystrokes from one computer to another by USB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706849/how-to-send-keystrokes-from-one-computer-to-another-by-usb)

Comment: By blue pill, google stm32 minimum development board keyboard emulator - anf you will have tens of ready HID keyboard devices projects

Answer (score -1):

You need to create some hardware + software. There are microcontroller demo boards for STM32 MCU, which contains a keyboard emulator firmware in their SDK. So, you should start to play with this demo board.