# creating virtual bluetooth device/service and let executing computer discover/use them

Tags: linux, bluetooth, linux-device-driver, bluez

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177186/is-it-possible-to-make-a-computer-behave-as-a-bluetooth-hid-device) question I sarted to wonder, whether it would be possible to not only let a program emulate a bluetooth device, but also let the (executing) computer think, that it is actually an external bluetooth device he'd be communicating with.

I looked into [bluez](http://www.bluez.org/) and [documentation](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html) concerning bluez, but couldn't find anything allowing me to feed bluetooth data to the device/computer or let the computer "discover" services running on himself.

Is this even possible using Linux/bluez?

Answer (score 1):

If you build a local version of BlueZ and use the switch `--enable-testing` it builds an  emulator for testing.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/README#n218

This would create 2 extra BLE adapters than can communicate with each other without going over the air:

`sudo ./emulator/btvirt -l2`

Same for br/edr:

`sudo emulator/btvirt -B -l2`