# iOS, Simulating HID Keyboard over USB

Tags: ios, ios8, mfi

### Environment

- Windows Desktop
- iOS8.* USB Connected to the Desktop machine
- libmibiledevice
- C++

### Use-case

Desktop to programatically Simulate an iOS HID keyboard.

**With Android this can be achieved using the [AOA2](https://source.android.com/accessories/aoa2.html) protocol, Does an equivalent exist for iOS? ( one that doesn't req HW implementation or re-packaging/hacking )**

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to not go down the USB path but rather use Bluetooth as iOS devices have support for pairing Bluetooth keyboards with them.  Any "real" Bluetooth keyboard can be paired with an iOS device, so assuming you can get another system to simulate a Bluetooth keyboard, you should be able to get it to pair with your iOS device.

A quick search turned up this question which might be of interest to you:
[Is it possible to make a computer behave as a bluetooth HID device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177186/is-it-possible-to-make-a-computer-behave-as-a-bluetooth-hid-device)

Comment: I have been on that path already, The Desktop machine I am using for control ( assuming BT ) is Windows Desktop, On windows, PSMs 0x11 & 0x13 are reserved for OS use, and thus, a BT HID device cannot be simulated on windows OS unless bthport.sys is patched ( see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5cdee4d6-03e1-403f-9f04-18938ea6ec68/patching-instructions-of-a-loaded-driver?forum=wdk for details )

Comment: Now lets assume that I have successfully patched bthport.sys to go around the reserved PSMs limitation, my App needs to be able to control multiple iOS devices ( Sigle desktop controls multiple devices ), this would mean that I'll need to have a BT USB dongle for each device being controlled ( as HID PSMs are constant on a per BT ~dongle~ basis ). All of the above makes me really want to explore options other than BT...